# How to Test Resource files?

Tags: .net

If a file is saved to \JavaScript\Resources\, the name of the file must be `Resources.<IETF Language Tag>.js`

All of the files in \JavaScript\Resources\ must have the same number of items in the resources class and any sub-classes.

All of the files in \JavaScript\Resources\ must have the same key names for items in the resources class and any sub-classes.

Comment: Could you post a small sample resource file? What kind of environment are you working in - pure JavaScript tests, .NET, Java, Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in .net then one way is to load the assemblies that contain the resources and enumerate and compare the resources contained in there.

```
//get resources from invariant assemlby
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(yourAssembly);
var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(yourAssembly.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage(),false, false);

foreach(var resource in resourceSet) {
    //I assume from your question that you know the cultures beforehand
    foreach(var cultureInfo in cultures) {
        var specificResource = resourceManager.GetString(resource, cultureInfo);
        if (specificResource == null)
            Assert.Fail("resource not found!");
    }
}
```

You should consider the above pseudo-code as I didn't test it at all. And there's always the option that a resource in the resourceset is not a string. You'd get an exception in that case.